# Outlook account is correctly set but I am not receiving any emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap

I have manually set account for my mail in the outlook.

I already have one email from the same domain and it is working normally now I wanted to put 2 more from the same domain and I am going trough the testing normally and I can send email normally but I am not able to receive any of emails on those 2 accounts.

What could be problem of that? It is set as IMAP account.

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2010 Professional Plus

Comment: You checked your incoming mail server and made sure it is the same as the working account along with the incoming server port numbers?

Comment: Port numbers are correct, everything is the same as the working account.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: there is no error, mail is normally sent and I can send it to that account but I am not receiving it

Comment: So when you click Send/Receive all; you do not get an error? Did you receive the test email when you set the account up?

Comment: no I haven't got the test message